# "Upgrading" SQL Server 2008 180-day Evaluation to Licenced Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I run into the same issue as someone who posted this question on experts-exchange.com (couldn't read the answer though as I don't have an account there):

*{Quote Begin}*
I noticed that the 180-day Evaluation version of SQL Server 2008 is the
Enterprise version. Is there going to be any problem "upgrading" the Evaluation Enterprise
version to a licensed *STANDARD* version (and how much additional stuff is going to be
left inactive on my disk and, more importantly, in my registry, etc. if I do
so)?
*{Quote End}*

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Side note about experts exchange: Scroll ALL the way to the bottom of the page (below the ads and such) to see the answers if you're not logged in...

Comment: @Chris_K: that only works if you get to the page through a google search result. The bad old pre-serverfault days. How I don't miss them.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there's some clever clever hacky way of doing this, for a production SQL server I think a clean install would be better. Backup your databases, uninstall the eval copy of SQL, install the new version you have, restore databases, job done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot downgrade SQL editions without re-installing the software.

You can, however, detach your databases from the Enterprise installation, uninstall, then install Standard edition and re-attach the databases.

As for cruft, there won't be anything of note unless you've made lots of odd tweaks and changes. You'll want to reboot between uninstalling Enterprise, and installing Standard.